# Ansible connection to docker engine on osx apple Silicon

Tags: docker, macos, ansible, apple-m1

I'm trying to connect to my local docker engine running on OSX (m1 chip) in order to create a dynamic inventory.
I've created a host file with the following config
I made sure that `docker_containers` module is well installed.

```
plugin: community.docker.docker_containers
docker_host: "unix://Users/ME/.docker/run/docker-cli-api.sock"
```

Then I run `ansible-inventory --graph -i ./hosts/hosts-docker-local.yaml`.

But I'm getting the following error:

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /Users/ME/Projects/ansible-test/hosts/hosts-docker-local.yaml with auto plugin: inventory source '/Users/ME/Projects/ansible-test/hosts/hosts-docker-local.yaml' could not be
verified by inventory plugin 'community.docker.docker_containers'
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /Users/ME/Projects/ansible-test/hosts/hosts-docker-local.yaml with yaml plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /Users/ME/Projects/ansible-test/hosts/hosts-docker-local.yaml with ini plugin: Invalid host pattern 'plugin:' supplied, ending in ':' is not allowed, this character is reserved to
provide a port.
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /Users/ME/Projects/ansible-test/hosts/hosts-docker-local.yaml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
@all:
  |--@ungrouped:
```

I tried

```
 ansible-doc -t inventory -l  | grep docker
community.docker.docker_containers                      Ansible dynamic inv...
community.docker.docker_machine                         Docker Machine inve...
community.docker.docker_swarm                           Ansible dynamic inv...
```

but somehow if I do this
`ansible localhost -i ./hosts/hosts-docker-local.yaml -m community.docker.docker_containers`

It complains

```
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The module community.docker.docker_containers was not found in configured module paths"
}

maybe something wrong with my module path, something wierd with OSX? (I installed Ansible with brew)
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_containers_inventory.html#synopsis): `Uses a YAML configuration file that ends with docker.[yml|yaml].` Yours ends with `*local.yaml`

Comment: yes i just figured this out! thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inventory file must end in `docker.yaml`, as pointed out by @Zeitounator.

> Uses a YAML configuration file that ends with `docker.[yml|yaml]`.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_containers_inventory.html#synopsis